# Unable to connect to wireless network. (Acer Travelmate 4152NLCi)

Tags: wireless, networking

Kinda new to Ubuntu :)

I don't have any knowledge about programming or tech stuff so, please go easy on me :).

I've decided to wipe my Windows XP os and decided to have ubuntu 12.10. It worked fine for a week then, my laptop suddenly lost the ability to connect to a wireless network. A notice will constantly pop up and ask for my WPA passphrase. Tried to type the correct password but it can't connect. The same notice keeps on popping up.

P.S. I've made sure the wifi toggle on the laptop is on.

The Specs:

- Intel Pentium M 740 (2MB L2 cache, 1.73Ghz, 533 Mhz FSB)
- Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 900
- 60 GB HDD
- 1.2 GB DDR2 RAM

Network Controller : Intel Corporation Pro/Wireless 2200BG

Comment: We need details about your wireless card. Please open a terminal and run and post: lspci -nn | grep 0280. The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i tried posting that but nothing happens :( . How do I check what wireless card i am using?

Comment: Try the terminal command: lspci -nn  Find the wireless card details and post them here in a comment or edit your original question.

Comment: I'll assume that its the net work controller. It's an Intel Corporation Pro/Wireless 2200BG

Comment: Look for errors or warnings in the message logs from the terminal: dmesg | grep ipw  The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.

Comment: Open a Terminal with **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **T** and type `sudo rfkill unblock all` and fill in your password. Then type `rfkill list all`. Finally try to reconnect.

Comment: @chili555 i did that and these show up [   23.361342] libipw: 802.11 data/management/control stack, git-1.1.13
[   23.361347] libipw: Copyright (C) 2004-2005 Intel Corporation <jketreno@linux.intel.com>
[   23.445294] ipw2200: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200/2915 Network Driver, 1.2.2kmprq
[   23.445299] ipw2200: Copyright(c) 2003-2006 Intel Corporation
[   23.561050] ipw2200: Detected Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection
[   23.711183] ipw2200: Detected geography ZZM (11 802.11bg channels, 0 802.11a channels)

Comment: @efthialex it didnt work :(

Comment: @JasonTong Try loading the module with the command `sudo modprobe ipw2200`